# Use regular expressions and inverse matching, and pipe it to another command

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, xargs

The thing is, I have a custom bash script that makes specific actions over the specified folder, with the syntax being:

```
myscript $1 $2 $3
```

Where `$1` is the name of the folder and `$2`, `$3` other necessary numeric arguments for the job.

Let's say I have a directory with many folders, for instance:

```
a
b
c
d
ref-1
ref-2
ref-3
```

I only need to execute the script on the folder not starting with `ref-`. As it would cost me a lot of effort to execute manually the script for each of the files, I want to figure out how to can I use regular expressions to limit just to the desired folders, using inverse matching like "extglob", and for each one of this execute the script with also the given `$2` and `$3` arguments.

Comment: Do you have to worry about files mixed in with folders, or does the main directory only contain sub-directories?

Comment: extglob effects globbing.  globbing and regular expressions are very different.

Answer (score 3):

you can `$(ls -d */|grep -v ^ref-)`, for instance.

Comment: This will generate output for "ref-1/foo".  You should pass "." as the argument to ls (or no argument.)

Comment: Right, but as I understand the OP wanted directories only, so my solution is specifying `-d` to `ls`, thanks for the comment.

Comment: What's the point of this construct? It will show exactly the same list with the dot appended to the end of each item?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, no, they didn't, I've added `-d` after your comment, that's exactly what I thanked you for. You pointed the problem, but I disagreed with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
ls !(ref-?)
```

or

```
ls !(ref*)
```

or

```
ls +({a..d})
```

or just

```
ls ?
```

EDIT:

The script could then be run so:

```
for first in !(ref-?); do script.sh $first $second $third; done
```

Where `second` and `third` are the numeric arguments.

Comment: Are you sure you've provided this samples for `bash`?

Comment: @dma_k as @b3yOnd3r indicated in his original question bash has advanced pattern matching which must be enabled by `shopt -s extglob`. Once it's enabled patterns such as `?(...), !(...), @(...), *(...) and +(...) can be used see [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you -

Using `find -type d` option you are limiting your find search to directories. Providing a `pattern with -not -name` can help you ignore the matched directories. `-exec option` can help you kick off your shell script for all the directories that have been found. `{} \;` just means a buffer space for exec to execute your shell script for each directory one at a time. `-depth n` will ensure it descends to n directory levels.

```
find . -not -name ref\* -not -name .\* -type d -depth 1 -exec ./script.sh {} \;
```

**UPDATE:**

My bad, I forgot about handling two user driven parameters. I may not be an expert but the easiest way I would think of doing is sending the find result to a file and then running the for loop on that file.

Something like this -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ find . -not -name ref\* -not -name .\* -type d -depth 1 > dirlist
[jaypal~/Temp]$ for i in dirlist; do ./script.sh $i param1 param2; done
```

Alternate way to pass user driven parameters (as suggested by @dma_k)

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ find . -not -name ref\* -not -name .\* -type d -depth 1 | xargs script.sh param1 param2
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it descends directory hierarchies, which may not matter if sub-directories such as `a` do not themselves have further sub-directories.  You may be able to use `depth -2` or a similar construct (the details of what is available vary from system to system).

Comment: Yea, I was just reading that info on the man page. I will update the answer right away. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. It seems this will do the job, but only one more thing is needed. How to use he selected folders in the buffer as the 1st argument (for each of this folders) and then use a 2nd and 3rd specified by the user?

Comment: @B3y0nd3r: That is done by `xargs`: `find . -not -name ref\* ... -depth 1 | xargs script.sh`

Comment: Thanks @dma_k. I have offered another solution in the update but yours is more sophisticated. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about    `ls | grep yourRegexHere`